# Update old apk with new

Tags: react-native, google-play, app-store, apk

I currently have an app in the play store/app store but recently I started getting problems on my debug version so I decided to create a new `react-native` project and copy/paste all my code.

Can I build this APK/IPA from this new project and upload it to the store without problems? Will Android/Apple decline my request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android as long as you use the same application id and the same keystore to sign the APK with you can recreate the app and submit it for review to add to store.
For Apple the important part is the bundle id. You need to set the bundle id as same and set the version number to correct one.